# Django Querying MongoDB ObjectIds in views from json object

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am currently working on querying MongoDB objects in Python Django and had no trouble in creating queries if it's the other attributes needed.

However I need to modify my queries to specifically filter through the ObjectIds returning one or no object found.

From my Javascript I am passing a json data to my Django `views.py` here's how it currently looks like:

```
def update(request):
   #AJAX data
   line = json.loads(request.body)

   _id = line['_id']
   print("OBJECT_ID: %s" % (_id))
   another_id = line['another_id']
   print("ANOTHER_ID: %s" % (another_id))
```

*Don't confuse the `another_id`, there are objects that has the same `another_id` s and unfortunately has to remain like that. That's why I can't query it for update since it will update all duplicates. This is the reason why I need the ObjectId.

For checking here's what it prints out:

```
{u'$oid': u'582fc95bb7abe7943f1a45b2'}
ANOTHER_ID: LTJ1277
```

Therefore I appended the query in `views.py` like this:

```
    try:
       Line.objects(_id=_id).update(set__geometry=geometry, set__properties=properties)
       print("Edited: " + another_id)
    except:
       print("Unedited.")
```

But it didn't return any object.

> So I was wondering if the query itself can't recognize the `$oid`in the json body as `"_id" : ObjectId("582fc95bb7abe7943f1a45b2")`?

*Edit:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
```

where I edited my `views.py` with:

```
    _id = line['_id']
    print("VALUES: %s" % (_id.get('$oid')))

    try:
    Line.objects(_id=ObjectId(_id.get('$oid'))).update(set__geometry=geometry, set__properties=properties)
```

Output:

```
VALUES: 582fc95bb7abe7943f1a498c
```

No luck. Still not querying/not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Using MongoDB with Django](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-django-mongo/) reference site:

> Notice that to access the unique object ID, you use "id" rather than "_id".

I tried revising the code from:

```
Line.objects(_id=ObjectId(_id.get('$oid'))).update(set__geometry=geometry, set__properties=properties)
```

to

```
Line.objects(id=ObjectId(_id.get('$oid'))).update(set__geometry=geometry, set__properties=properties)
```

...And it now works fine. Keeping this question for others who might need this.